# The environment variable is not set

Tags: python, flask, embedded, environment-variables, embedded-linux

I use environment variable to pass settings file:

```
app.config.from_envvar('DVR_SETTINGS')
```

It works fine on my dev system but when I try to deploy this thing on embedded linux system (arago) I get this:

```
RuntimeError: The environment variable 'DVR_SETTINGS' is not set and as such configuration could not be loaded.
Set this variable and make it point to a configuration file
```

But I have done it:

```
root@dm365-evm:/var/www/dvr# echo $DVR_SETTINGS
/var/www/dvr/settings/production.py
```

Comment: And how is your Flask server run then?

Comment: I've just tried to run dev server that comes with flask. When I used object for config, it worked.

Comment: So *in the same environment, in the same shell* where you just tested `DVR_SETTINGS` is set, you ran the dev server?

Comment: *All* that Flask does is `os.environ.get(variable_name)` here. If you run a Python prompt and do `import os; print os.environ.keys()`, is the specific variable listed?

Comment: Did you *export* the environment variable? `export DVR_SETTINGS`?

Comment: I added it to `/etc/profile`, it didn't work. Then I tried `export`. It didn't work too...

Comment: Something simple is being overlooked, but I cannot tell you what without access to your environment, I'd say. I cannot reproduce your problem in any case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yeah, you were right. Thanks. I'm just confused with assignments and exports. It always happens to me.

Comment: @MartijnPieters May you post this as an answer so this question can be closed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *export* the environment variable:

```
export DVR_SETTINGS
```

You can combining setting and exporting in one line:

```
export DVR_SETTINGS=/var/www/dvr/settings/production.py
```

or you can put it on the line running your Flask server:

```
DVR_SETTINGS=/var/www/dvr/settings/production.py python flask_script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

In OS windows you need to export the environment variable:

- print(os.environ)  you can see a list of all environment
- set  "environment variable"